# tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Tags: linux, doctrine, compression, gzip, tar

when I untar doctrine

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 660252 2010-10-16 23:06 Doctrine-1.2.0.tgz
```

I always get this error messages

```
root@X100e:/usr/local/lib/Doctrine/stable# tar -xvzf Doctrine-1.2.0.tgz

.
.
.

Doctrine-1.2.0/tests/ViewTestCase.php
Doctrine-1.2.0/CHANGELOG

gzip: stdin: decompression OK, trailing garbage ignored
Doctrine-1.2.0/COPYRIGHT
Doctrine-1.2.0/LICENSE
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

The untar operation works, but I always get this error messages.

Any clues what I do wrong?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I would try to unzip and untar separately and see what happens:

```
mv Doctrine-1.2.0.tgz Doctrine-1.2.0.tar.gz
gunzip Doctrine-1.2.0.tar.gz
tar xf Doctrine-1.2.0.tar
```

Comment: indeed, the error is gone. not sure what is causing it though.

Comment: I encountered this error today when trying to unzip and untar mediawiki-1.18.0.tar.gz . I re-downloaded mediawiki-1.18.0.tar.gz and the errors stopped, so I assume the file must have been corrupted during the initial download.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible your tar file is not zipped. I just had this same error, but all I had was a plain old tar file. So try just removing the z from your flags. The z flag unzips your tar file as well as whatever other commands you requested with other flags. i.e. try:

```
tar -xvf Doctrine-1.2.0.tgz
```

Notice I removed the z from -xvzf

Answer (score 2):

If you got **"Error is not recoverable: exiting now"** You might have specified incorrect path references.

```
[me@host ~]$ tar -xvf nameOfMyTar.tar -C /someSubDirectory/
tar: /someSubDirectory: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
[me@host ~]$
```

Make sure you provide **correct relative or absolute directory references** e.g.:

```
[me@host ~]$ tar -xvf ./nameOfMyTar.tar -C ./someSubDirectory/
./foo/
./bar/
[me@host ~]$
```

Comment: You are not answering the original question, but fixing a different error.

Comment: Right, I don't answer the users specific question, but the error message in the title is the same as mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get your archive using `wget`, I had the same issue when I was downloading archive through browser. Than I just copy archive link and in terminal use the command:

```
wget http://PATH_TO_ARCHIVE
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you do not have bzip2 installed. The tar program relies upon this external program to do compression.
For installing bzip2, it depends on the system you are using. For example, with Ubuntu that would be on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install bzip2
```

The GNU tar program does not know how to compress an existing file such as user-logs.tar (bzip2 does that). The tar program can use external compression programs gzip, bzip2, xz by opening a pipe to those programs, sending a tar archive via the pipe to the compression utility, which compresses the data which it reads from tar and writes the result to the filename which the tar program specifies.

Alternatively, the tar and compression utility could be the same program. BSD tar does its compression using lib archive (they're not really distinct except in name).

Answer (score 1):

use sudo

```
sudo tar -zxvf xxxxxxxxx.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Error messages
[image]

Easy way to fix this issue

> 1. First Remove files
> 2. Download file again
> 3. Extract file again ( tar -xzvf(or -xvf) FreeFileSync**.tar.gz

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error code:

```
tar -xvfz processed.json.gz

tar: z: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Turned out the file had the .gz extension but wasn't compressed. Just removed the .gz and opened it.