# extract good files from corrupt tar archive

Tags: linux

I have a large tar archive with many xml files in it. a couple of xml files in this archive are corrupt. How can I extract the good files without the program exiting?

There is a tar file within the gz

```
tar zxf myFile.gz

tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: rmtlseek not stopped at a record boundary
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: this belongs on [su], not stackoverflow.

Comment: how to i Move it to super user? should i delete here and create in super user?

Comment: you have seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950839/tar-error-is-not-recoverable-exiting-now, you must do it in 2 step

Answer (score 1):

It looks, from the filename, as though you're trying to unpack something that isn't a tar archive. Usually a tar file would have a `.tar` extension, and if it had been then compressed with gzip, it would be `.tar.gz` or `.tgz`.

The command you're running, with the `z` option to `tar`, tries to undo gzip compression first, and then untar the resulting archive. But from the `.gz` extension, it rather looks as though you've got a gzipped file rather than a gzipped tar archive.

The best thing to do is to examine the file to find out what sort of file it is:

```
file myFile.gz
```

That will tell you whether it's gzipped or whatever. If it's gzipped, then run

```
gunzip myFile.gz
```

That will leave you with `myFile` without the extension; you can then use

```
file myFile
```

to probe it to determine whether it's a tar archive or something else.

Comment: gunzip gives me a tar file

Comment: I think in that case your best bet, if it's not a private thing, is to post it up somewhere to see if anyone can work out what to do with it.

Comment: the file is private and also 50 Gb in size

Answer (score 0):

- `mv myFile.gz myFile.tar.gz`
- `gunzip myfile.tar.gz`
- `tar xf myFile.tar`

Comment: I tried gunzip which gives me a tar file with the same results

Comment: @SantoshPillai  : I have edited my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: I am seeing this when I try to gunzip: [root@server xml]# gunzip myFile.tar.gz
    gzip: myFile.tar.gz: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0):

You might try bzip2recover to try recover the bondaries first!

```
bzip2recover file.bzip
```

eg from manual:
In case of damage to one member of a .gz file, other members can still be  recovered  (if  the
file: Corrupt input. Use zcat to recover some data.

```
usage: zcat file > recover
```